# What can git-add do that git update-index can't?

Tags: git

From the research I've come across, they both seem to do the same thing. From the git documentation, git-add adds the file contents to the index while git update-index 'registers' it. Not sure what is meant by register and how that differs from add.

Comment: I already saw that but the answers are not that detailed.

Comment: `git-add ` uses `git update-index` to preform the action. Are you asking what `git-add` does in addition to `git update-index`?

Comment: Yes - sorry if my question was confusing.

Comment: @MattSizzle: that used to be the case—that `git add` invoked `git update-index`—but in modern Git, both are coded in C (well, mostly; `git add -p` and `git-add--interactive` are separate programs and the patch add variant at least is in Perl) so much of what `git add` does is built in to the C code.

Answer (score 2):

As a user-facing (or [*porcelain*](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefporcelainaporcelain)) command, `git add` has a lot of user-oriented features, including:

- [*Pathspec*](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec) arguments: `git update-index` does not use or accept pathspecs, but `git add` does, so `git add :(attr:text)/` would add only files marked specifically "text" in `.gitattributes`, for instance.
- The options `-a`, `-A`, `--ignore-removal`, `-u`, and so on.
- An interactive mode (which I never use and have never gotten the hang of).
- The `--patch` or `-p` option, which invokes a separate Perl program that creates a diff between the index and work-tree copies of a file and lets you pick and choose parts of that diff to apply to the index.

There are no doubt additional things not covered here, and will be more over time.  Meanwhile, as a [*plumbing*](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefplumbingaplumbing) command, `git update-index` has abilities that are not suitable for direct use by humans, such as the ability to put files into particular staging slots.